# Is there a way to export the output of the command `show_transfers`?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

When entering `show_transfers` into monero-wallet-cli, one is provided a list of in- and out- transactions related to that wallet.  Is there a way to use that command to export the data into a txt, csv, or other type of file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

To write the output of a command to a file, there are basically 8 commonly used ways.

#### Overview:

```
         || visible in terminal ||   visible in file   || existing
 Syntax  ||  StdOut  |  StdErr  ||  StdOut  |  StdErr  ||   file   
=========++==========+==========++==========+==========++===========
   >     ||    no    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    || overwrite
   >>    ||    no    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    ||  append
         ||          |          ||          |          ||
  2>     ||   yes    |    no    ||    no    |   yes    || overwrite
  2>>    ||   yes    |    no    ||    no    |   yes    ||  append
         ||          |          ||          |          ||
  &>     ||    no    |    no    ||   yes    |   yes    || overwrite
  &>>    ||    no    |    no    ||   yes    |   yes    ||  append
         ||          |          ||          |          ||
| tee    ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    || overwrite
| tee -a ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    ||  append
```

#### List:

- `command > output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command >> output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.
- `command 2> output.txt`

  The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command 2>> output.txt`

  The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.
- `command &> output.txt`

  Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command &>> output.txt`

  Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file..
- `command | tee output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command | tee -a output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be copied to the file only, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

Comment: For future viewers, use the `--command` option to accomplish this from the shell, i.e., `$ monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file <file> --command show_transfers > transfers.txt`

Comment: Also note that the password prompt will not be shown (unless this is eventually changed/fixed), so you must then enter your password for it to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

You can always copy/paste from the terminal, or if you could do it by RPC and pipe the output to a text file.